# Wget post data with text box that has randomly generated value?

Tags: bash, post, authentication, wget, router

I'm trying to use Wget to log in to my router and make a complete mirror of all the pages. The problem is, the router login page does not use the traditional "user" & "pass" ID for the text fields. It has a 'Password' and 'VmWpsPin' field. The ID for the 'Password' field is randomly generated every time the page is loaded/refreshed/requested. Below is the source code of the relevant part of the router page:

```html
<body lang="en" class="superhubGUI" onload="javascript:Init()">
  <div class="globalHeader">
    <div id="nav">
      <div id="logo">
        <h1 id="header">Super Hub</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="buttons"><a href="../RouterStatus.html" class="routerStatus">Router Status</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="main">
        <div class="panel noTitle" style="*padding:38px 30px 0px 30px">
          <div id="login" class="inner">
            <div class="inner-section">
              <h2>Welcome to your Virgin Media Super Hub 2ac</h2>
              <div id="signInForm">
                <form action="/cgi-bin/VmLoginCgi" method="POST" name="signIn1" id="signIn">
                  <h2 id="loginTitle">Sign in to view and change your settings</h2>
                  <div class="field formField noHint username clearfix">
                    <label for="username"></label>
                  </div>
                  <div style="position:relative;top:-20px;" class="field formField noHint password clearfix">
                    <label for="password">Settings Password</label>
                    <input type="password" autocomplete="off" value="" maxlength="15" class="name required onefiftyPX inactive" name="KsCAqiihZb" id="password" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)" />
                    <div style="position:relative;left:-10px;" class="tooltip">
                      <img style="position:absolute; top:10px;" src="../images/toolTipButton.png"><span>Password can be found on the base of your Super Hub</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div style="position:relative;top:-25px;" class="field formField noHint password clearfix">
                    <label for="password">WPS PIN</label>
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" maxlength="15" class="name required onefiftyPX inactive" name="VmWpsPin" id="WpsPin" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)" />
                    <div style="position:relative;left:-10px;" class="tooltip">
                      <img style="position:absolute; top:10px;" src="../images/toolTipButton.png"><span>WPS PIN can be found on the base of your Super Hub</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <a href="javascript:SignIn()" class="newCta ctaLarge ctaPrimaryLarge floatLeft">Sign In</a>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <p>
                  <span style="font-weight:bold;">Don't know your password?</span>
                  <br/>You'll find your default password on the bottom of your Super Hub.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><span class="pFoot">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

My question is, how can I use Wget to login to the router when the ID changes at every request, is there somehow a way to request the page, parse the value out and then submit the form using something like --keep-session?

Or is there an alternative solution outside of Wget to automate the process? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: For clarity, you are saying that id="WpsPin" changes every time you reload the page?

Comment: Did not mean to post that question as an answer. If that is what you are trying to achieve, why not do a search for that string and set it as a variable in a script. Something like `passText=$(grep -o "\<name=.*VmWpsPin.* id=.*\>" | grep -oe 'id=.*"')`

Comment: If you ran `echo ${passText}` that variable should display **id="WpsPin"** or whatever the page randomly has generated for that.

Comment: Sorry I meant the "name" of the ID field for password changes. In the above example its: name="KsCAqiihZb" id="password". when using TamperData plugin to see what information is posted when you login it sends the name of the field i.e. in this case "KsCAqiihZb" but that value changes at every page request. I'll try what you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to just change what grep is searching for ti find that. Example: `passText=$(grep -o "\<name=.* id=password\>" | grep -oe 'name=.*"')`